# Find matching points in 2 separate numpy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy, compare

I have two arrays of different sizes containing 3d points. I would like to efficiently compare the two arrays and find the points that match and ultimately return a simple number of matching points.

```
pA=[[0,0,0],[0,1,0],[1,2,4],[10,3,4],[1,20,1],[5,3,2]]
pB=[[14,1,0],[1,2,4],[1,20,1],[15,1,0]]

#returns 2
```

Currently I have a sloppy loop that does the trick, but it is not very performance friendly which is a problem considering I am trying to match many pairs of arrays with a larger number of points

```
t= np.array([pA[x]==pB for x in range(len(pA))]).sum(2)
print np.sum(t==3)
```

I'm just not sure how to efficiently compare two multidimensional arrays of different sizes. And then how to do multiple iterations for a large number of pairs.

EDIT

Found a bit of a workaround which is pretty fast that combines the arrays, makes a unique version of the array, and then compares the lengths of the two arrays.

```
pts=np.concatenate((pA,pB),axis=0)
pts2 = np.unique(pts.view([('', pts.dtype)]*pts.shape[1]))
return len(pts)-len(pts2)
```

Comment: Could there be repetitions of points within each list?

Answer (score 3):

No idea how this performs on your full dataset but try using Scipy's kdtree:

```
from scipy.spatial import cKDTree

pA=[[0,0,0],[0,1,0],[1,2,4],[10,3,4],[1,20,1],[5,3,2]]
pB=[[14,1,0],[1,2,4],[1,20,1],[15,1,0]]

kdtree = cKDTree(pA)
dists, inds = kdtree.query(pB, distance_upper_bound=1e-5)
result = (dists == 0).sum()
```

- http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.cKDTree.html#scipy.spatial.cKDTree

Comment: Scipy definitely seems to have tools that would work well with this problem. Only issue is that this is for a script that is to run in Autodesk Maya and I would need to compile the Scipy module for this particular Maya version (something I have no experience in doing). Might not be too hard though if it is necessary.

Comment: I see. Does numpy with with Maya then?

Comment: Numpy I was able to find a compiled version for Maya. In my brief search I was unable to find a Scipy one. I may have to put more effort into getting Scipy working in Maya though since it seems to have some better functions for 3D from what little I have seen.

Comment: You might have luck with a pure-Python implementation like this: https://github.com/stefankoegl/kdtree . Or maybe there's another simple and efficient method. Worth mentioning your Maya constraint in the question though.

Comment: Seems like kdtree is quite useful when it comes to `numpy`. Good to know about it!

Comment: I will definitely have to give it a shot and learn how to properly use kdtrees. They definitely seem to be the way to go for things like this.

Comment: Cool. Also thinking about it, see how fast simply doing a set intersection is. You will need to convert your points to tuples. Eg something like len(set(tuple(x) for x in pa).intersection (...))

Answer (score 1):

Here's one approach using just `numpy` operations. The basic idea here is that we concatenate those two lists into one numpy array. Then, we sort it row-wise to bring the matching points at consecutive rows. Next up, we do `diff` to get all zero rows for the matching ones, which is *picked up* by `np.all(...==0,1)`. We count all those occurrences to give us the desired output of count of matching points between those two lists.

The implementation is listed below -

```
import numpy as np

# Inputs
pA=[[0,0,0],[0,1,0],[1,2,4],[10,3,4],[1,20,1],[5,3,2]]
pB=[[14,1,0],[1,2,4],[1,20,1],[15,1,0]]

# Form concatenate array of pA and pB
pts = np.concatenate((pA,pB),axis=0)

# Sort pts by rows
spts = pts[pts[:,1].argsort(),]

# Finally get counts by DIFFing along rows and counting all zero rows
counts = np.sum(np.diff(np.all(np.diff(spts,axis=0)==0,1)+0)==1)
```

Output -

```
In [152]: counts
Out[152]: 2
```

The above code works even if you have duplicate points in either of the lists. So, let's add some duplicate points in the inputs of the earlier code -

```
# Inputs
pA=[[0,0,0],[0,1,0],[1,2,4],[10,3,4],[1,20,1],[5,3,2],[1,2,4]]
pB=[[14,1,0],[1,2,4],[1,20,1],[15,1,0],[1,2,4]]
```

After code run with the modified inputs, the output still remains as `2` which is the expected output.

If you are sure that there are no duplicate entries in either of the lists, you can use a simplified version to replace the last step -

```
counts = np.sum(np.all(np.diff(spts,axis=0)==0,1))
```

Comment: This idea is essentially what I have in use at the moment, though I am sure yours is much more elegant. My variation concatenates the arrays and then creates a new array with all duplicate entries removed and compares the two array lengths to get the number.

`pts=np.concatenate((pA,pB),axis=0)
pts2 = np.unique(pts.view([('', pts.dtype)]*pts.shape[1]))
counts = len(pts)-len(pts2)`

Comment: @AlexRideout Yes, that `all + diff` part is essentially `unique` finding in a *raw* version, and might be efficient as it also avoids intermediate variable creation. Added a simplified version at the end of the new edits to the solution for lists with no duplicate entries. Just curious, if you had a chance to test out these approaches for runtime performance?

Comment: Your approach definitely seems more elegant than my `unique` method. I haven't had the chance to do any official measurements as far as exact time goes. Mostly have only done subjective tests on the geometry in my Maya scenes. I am currently using a loop to iterate through all of the pairs of point arrays I have generated (perhaps some way to vectorize this step?) and this runs through roughly 6,000 pairs/second which is somewhat acceptable for my implementation. Though I have been dealing with upwards of 200,000 pairs, so not perfectly ideal.